# How to delete multiple rows in database using datagridview?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I want to delete multiple rows in database from datagridview. When I use the code below, all the rows preceding the selected row gets deleted instead of just selected rows. Please help.

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdDelete.Click

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvMasterTable.SelectedRows

        SQL.DataUpdate("DELETE FROM MASTER WHERE Item_id ='" & row.DataBoundItem(0) & "' ") 
        next        

End Sub
```

Comment: Is your `Item_id` definitely the same as the value of `row.DataBoundItem(0)`?

Comment: @MahendranNadesan sorry for posting this question. The same code actually works now. I found out that the code did not work because of some error in other codes. Thanks a lot any way.